Does $H^1(U;\Bbb C)=0$ suffice to show $\int_{\partial U}f=0$?
The following result is classical (and proven excellently, without any hand-waving, in Conway's "Functions of one complex variable"):

Let $\Omega\subset\Bbb C$ be a nonempty connected open subset, $f:\Omega\to\Bbb C$ holomorphic.  Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to\Omega$ be a nonconstant, closed smooth curve such that $\Bbb C\setminus K\subset\Omega$ where $K$ is the unique unbounded component of $\Bbb C\setminus\gamma^\ast$ i.e. $\Omega$ contains $\gamma$ and its interior $U=(\Bbb C\setminus\gamma^\ast)\setminus K$ (by a local application of the Jordan theorem, we know that $U$ is nonempty). Then: $$\oint_{\gamma}f=0$$More strongly, $$n(\gamma;z)\cdot f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,d\gamma(w)$$For any $z\in\Omega$.

I have a half-baked idea to prove this without really doing any complex analysis, and am here to ask for your help in making it work. For conceptual reasons.
It's folklore that much of complex analysis can be viewed through the lens of algebraic topology, in particular sheaf theory. For example, the more elementary Cauchy-Goursat argument for a triangular contour can be used to check exactness of the following sequence of sheaves:
$$0\to\underline{\Bbb C}\to\mathcal{O}\overset{d/dz}{\longrightarrow}\mathcal{O}\to0$$On $\Bbb C$, $\mathcal{O}$ the holomorphic functions sheaf; then, if $H^1(\Omega;\Bbb C)=0$ (sheaf and singular and Cech cohomology theories all coincide for open subsets of $\Bbb C$) we find that differentiation is surjective: $\mathcal{O}(\Omega)\overset{d/dz}{\twoheadrightarrow}\mathcal{O}(\Omega)$ so our $f$ admits a primitive $F$, and then it is obvious that $\oint_{\gamma}f=0$ for closed smooth curves.
So, I was thinking about how to push this further - I hope to conclude the above version of Cauchy's theorem using cohomological tools only (given, as I've said, only the more basic theory on an open disc).
My question:
I can prove, using some duality theorems, that $H^1(U;\Bbb C)=0$ where $U\subset\Omega$ is the interior of $\gamma$. Therefore, $f$ has a primitive $F:U\to\Bbb C$ with $F'=f$ on $U$. Unfortunately, that does not immediately seem to give me that $F$ extends to a primitive of $f$ on some small neighbourhood of $U\cup\gamma^\ast$, which is what I'd need to use this to conclude $\oint_{\gamma}f=0$. Is this calculation good enough? I'm hoping there may be a good approximation argument where $\oint_{\gamma}f=\oint_{\Gamma}f$ for some $\Gamma$ which lands in $U$, and then I could be done.
My title is a little bit dishonest since I'm not sure if $\gamma^\ast=\partial U$ actually holds. I've seen ways to argue this in the case of $\gamma$ being a simple closed curve but they don't seem to generalise, as typically $\gamma^\ast$ is not a manifold.
